# C++ Any way to programmatically detect POD-struct?

Tags: c++

I have data structure which stores POD-structs (each instantiation stores a single type only, since it is basically an array of a specific POD-struct).  Sometimes another dev. will modify one of these structs, adding or modifying a data type.  If a non-POD element is added, e.g. std::string, the data structure blows-up at runtime, because the memory model changes.  Is there any way to detect if a class or struct is POD-compliant using compiler defines or a call at run-time (to avoid this maintainence issue) ?  I'm using g++ (GCC) 4.2.4.

Comment: The usual approach to solve this problem is code review.

Comment: @unapersson:  Code reviews will often fail to detect a problem in this case, especially in larger code bases.  Compiler support is a better approach.

Comment: @John Not. Code reviews are the best way of detecting almost all semantic (rather than syntactic) problems with code.

Comment: @unapersson: I cannot agree in this case. In all cases where the compiler can trigger an error, it will do it *always*, while code reviews can skip some cases. Someone might be using a type `X` in the container, and that type might contain another type `Y`, which in turn contains `Z`... which might be changed to be a non-pod. Since the type `Z` is never directly used in the container, the source of the problem and the problem itself are separated and in many cases it will not be detected. No matter how far the definition of `Z` is, the compiler can catch this up much earlier than any review.

Comment: @unapersson:  My assertion is based on experience.  I have been involved in many multi-MLOC projects with objects that would break if they were changed to be a non-POD, and code reviews sometimes failed to find the defect.  When we developed compile-time tools that would break the compile when these things were changed, the defect-detection rate become 100% immediately.  How can a code review ever be better than this?  Don't get me wrong, code reviews are great for many reasons -- but they aren't the end-all, be-all.

Comment: @David The static_assert && is_pod combo posted by the topvoted answerer certainly looks good, but at the end of the day it breaks a build. The good thing about code reviews is that they instill into the programmers the knowledge of the architecture of the project, so they won't be tempted  to introduce things like std::string into (I assume) C-style structs. which break a build. Not everything in our industry can usefully be automated.

Comment: @unapersson:  The compiler can not detect a purely semantic error, of course.  But many semantic errors can be re-expressed as compile-time entities, and then the compiler can help you find semantic errors by making broken code impossible to compile.  OP's requirement for a particular structure to be a POD can easily be re-expressed as a syntactic test.  The compiler will look at every line of code.  Code reviews won't.

Comment: @unapersson:  Breaking a build is far better than releasing broken code in to the wild.

Comment: @John "Breaking a build is far better than releasing broken code in to the wild." Of course, but writing code that didn't break the build in the first place should be the ultimate target.

Comment: @unapersson:  That's the ultimate target, I agree.  In the real world, programmers will never write defect-free code.  Teach the newbies in code reviews.  But don't expect the code reviews to catch everything.  They never do, and never will.

Comment: @John Most of the best code reviews I've had have been conducted by experienced programmers. They are not primarily a tool for inducting newbies, though they of course have that side-effect.

Comment: @unapersson: I'm sure they said the same thing about `const` before it was introduced into C. "We detect via code review whether or not a given object is modified - introducing a compiler check just breaks the build". And any kind of static typing, for that matter. Languages like Python, where "compile-time checking" is pretty much restricted to simple syntax-validity, are useful, but they aren't C++. In any case, if you can't stop code that doesn't compile from reaching the build, how on earth do you stop code that hasn't been reviewed from reaching the build?

Comment: @Steve I am (I would have thought obviously) not suggesting one somehow turn off all C++ compiler checks and depend on code reviews for everything. I am suggesting that there are many semantic bugs which cannot be resolved by a compiler, and which can only be spotted by  a code review.

Comment: @unapersson: and fortunately, once C++0x (or another working `is_pod` implementation) arrives in your compiler this will no longer be one of them :-). My objection wasn't to solving by code review problems that can't be found by the compiler, it was to, "but at the end of the day it breaks a build". So does any compiler check, if flawed code makes it into the build, but normally such flaws should be identified *before* code review, when the programmer compiles the code.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

At runtime probably not, but at compile time, you can use `is_pod` trait from either C++0x standard library or [Boost.TypeTraits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/type_traits/index.html).

```
static_assert(std::is_pod<YourStruct>::value);
```

Comment: In C++03 this is only half a solution. You have to manually specialize the template for your own types, which puts you right back at square one.  Somebody changes a type somewhere, but `is_pod<T>::value` still yields true, so the later `static_assert` happily passes.  Its better than nothing, but you have to be careful it doesn't lead to a false sense of security.

Comment: @DennisZickeoose: Depends on the compiler. MSVC (at least >=2005, possibly older), GCC >=4.3 (I think) and some others have intrinsics that `is_pod` uses. So if you're using an ancient or otherwise incapable compiler, then yes, it might not be a good solution.

Comment: And as the OP is using GCC4.2, its a pretty important distinction.

Comment: @DennisZickeoose: Ah, right. Well, there's an easy solution for that problem, don't use ancient and unsupported compilers. ;) I'd still say is_pod is the best way to go, even if it requires a compiler upgrade.

Comment: This is good information - thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately, I can't switch compilers at this point - believe me, I wish I could.

Answer (score 9):

You can probably use boost type_traits library and in particular `boost::is_pod<T>::value` in an static assert.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have boost or C++0x then you can perhaps use some fact like that C++ does not let to use non-POD as member of union.

Comment: its written in imperfect c++ :D