# Is there a valid use case where a non-POD struct is preferred to a class?

Tags: c++, class, struct, language-history

According to the (2003) standard's definition of a struct, it is a specialized case of a class, with different default access modifiers for members, functions, and base classes.  It also goes on to define the requirements of a struct to be a POD-struct.

C++ 2003 Standard, ISO 14882 Section 9.0.4:

> A structure is a class defined with the class-key struct; its members and base classes (clause 10) are public
>   by default (clause 11). A union is a class defined with the class-key union; its members are public by
>   default and it holds only one data member at a time (9.5). [Note: aggregates of class type are described in
>   8.5.1. ] A POD-struct is an aggregate class that has no non-static data members of type non-POD-struct,
>   non-POD-union (or array of such types) or reference, and has no user-defined copy assignment operator
>   and no user-defined destructor. Similarly, a POD-union is an aggregate union that has no non-static data
>   members of type non-POD-struct, non-POD-union (or array of such types) or reference, and has no userdefined
>   copy assignment operator and no user-defined destructor. A POD class is a class that is either a
>   POD-struct or a POD-union.

Given this definition, the only differentiating factor between a non-POD struct and a class is the default access modifier.

Here's what I could imagine as the purpose of having non-POD structs:

- They're a legacy feature that needs to be maintained for backwards-compatibility
- Typing `public:` is hard.

Having non-POD structs can lead to pain when they're assumed to be POD by other systems, for example when passed around to C and back.  To illustrate, [this person ran into problems when a struct that was assumed to be POD was updated by another developer such that it was no longer POD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955444/c-any-way-to-programmatically-detect-pod-struct).  Because POD-ness isn't statically asserted by the compiler by default, the application would crash at run-time when that struct was used in contexts where only POD structs could be used.  Even worse, I could imagine (though I don't know for certain if this is possible) a non-POD struct working in certain circumstances that require POD, and failing in others, leading to errors and crashes that are nothing short of arduous to track down.

Seeing as there are situations where having non-POD structs can lead to the realm of bizarre and broken behavior, what is the use of non-POD structs?  Why aren't structs statically checked for POD-ness at compile-time (via std::is_pod in C++11 or the Boost equivalent)?

Comment: *"the only differentiating factor between a non-POD struct and a class is the default access modifier"* -- It's the only difference between a struct and a class *period*, not just non-POD structs/classes.

Comment: This question is really poorly stated. What you're really asking is "why are `struct`s just `class`es with default public accessors?" It has nothing to do with the definition of POD or standard-layout or aggregates or whatever.

Comment: I apologize, I probably could have worded this better.  My question isn't why structs and classes are differentiated, but rather why it's possible to make a struct that's not POD, when they're the same as classes with some inconsequential differences.  Sorry, I hope this describes my question a little more concisely.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's a pointless historical accident, and frankly the `class` keyword never should have been added in C++ at all.  Oh well!

It would often be annoying if a `struct` was required to be POD--you'd often start out with something POD, call it a "struct" just because you could, and then wind up having to change it in many places later on when you decide to make it non-POD.

Note that GCC (at least until recently) did not care if you (forward) declared something as a class in one place and as a struct elsewhere, or vice versa.  Clang complains about this sort of thing (as it has every right to, though this does "break" some existing code).

Comment: A compiler has every right to issue any diagnostics that it wants to. However, g++ *must accept* the differences in declarations. And diagnosing it is a [counter-productive silly-warning](http://alfps.wordpress.com/2010/06/22/cppx-is-c4099-really-a-sillywarning-disabling-msvc-sillywarnings/), since it can only be diagnosed in the case where it's harmless.

Comment: Same thing goes for template specializations, you can specialize a class template as a struct and vice-versa.

Comment: *has every right to do it [complain about mixing `struct` and `class` declarations]* I really don't think so, can you explain why a compiler should *complain*? Where is it stated that it is incorrect? Note that on the opposite end, Visual Studio (in my opinion,until you prove me wrong) has a problem in that it mangles symbols for struts and classes differently, while regarding the standard the only difference is the default access specifier, which has no effect in declarations... Do you care to explain your claim?

Comment: I don't mind that both struct and class exist in the language, I'm just confused why non-POD structs and classes both serve the same purpose, albeit with some inconsequential differences.  I don't think it would be annoying if changing a struct to a non-pod struct made it break existing code.  I find that analogous to starting with a const instance, and then determining that you need to edit that const instance.

Comment: _why a compiler should complain? Where is it stated that it is incorrect?_ - I don't think it's strictly incorrect by the standard.  Clang complains about many things that it thinks are not good despite being legal C or C++. -- _Visual Studio has a problem in that it mangles symbols for struts and classes differently_ - I don't use MSVC, and while that sounds unfortunate, is it a real problem, given the ODR?  Does it mangle the name of the class type itself differently if you forward declare it as a struct and then say make a pointer to one of those?

Comment: In VS if you declare as struct and then define or redeclare as class the compiler complains and fails to compile. If different translation units refer to the same type in different ways the mangled symbols won't match and you will get *undefined symbols* rather than multiply defined symbols. I don't use VS to test this now. Heck I don't even have a computer! I bet that the warning is just to avoid potential problems with VS.

Answer (score 0):

> “POD-ness isn't statically asserted by the compiler by default”

Oh?

```
#include <iostream>         // std::cout, std::endl
#include <type_traits>      // std::is_pod
#include <string>           // std::string, std::to_string
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    int x;
};

struct B
{
    string s;
};

int main()
{
    static bool const a = is_pod<A>::value;
    static_assert( a, "Ah..." );
    static_assert( !is_pod<B>::value, "Bah!" );
}
```

The reason that `struct` is allowed to be non-POD, as e.g. `B` above, i.e. *why the language is designed this way*, is probably to be found in Bjarne Stroustrup’s book “The Design and Evolution of C++”. And if not, then probably only Bjarne himself knows. Because this C++ generality of `struct` has been there since the very beginning.

Comment: I wouldn't say the compiler is doing that 'by default'. Not that it should.

Comment: Yeah I specifically mentioned std::is_pod.  My question was more along the lines of "why doesn't it do this *by default*?

Comment: @barnes53: I would not say that the OP's statement makes much sense at all. There is no case at all where the (language rules require that the) compiler asserts PODness. So what's this about a "by default"? I can't see any sensible interpretation.

Comment: @grahamp: The answer is simple: Because not everybody wants that feature. "You pay only for what you need".

Comment: @grahamp: OK, I added a paragraph about that at the end. But the upshot is that it is probably quite arbitrary, due to no longer relevant historical reasons.